# Having low download speed( ~10KBps ) with tracker status "Connection timed out" on a gigabit internet network

Tags: internet, ethernet

I recently upgraded from **100 Mbps** to **1 gigabit** internet. Though I am getting reasonable speed both uploading and downloading, I am unable to download torrents at that speed. It shows around **10 KBps**.
Tracker status shows

> Connection timed out

I think tcp settings are causing these issues but I am not sure. Can anyone explain what the issue is and what to do to resolve it?

Comment: Network speed is determined by the slowest link - if there's only a total of 10 KBps available being uploaded from others, that is all you will get. What are you torrenting? Linux Distros??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information on your particular setup I can only provide some generic information:

- Could be your internet provider throttles torrent traffic. This is not unheard of.
- Possibly the tracker(s) you are using are being firewalled by your provider.
- The virusscanner/firewall on your own computer is getting in the way. (Either blocking stuff or slowing things down due to excessive scanning.)
- The tracker(s) themselves are just slow.
- The torrents you are downloading just have slow seeders.
- Manually configuring TCP parameters for torrent traffic was a big thing a few years ago and you will still see people recommending to apply all sorts of TCP "tweaks" and "optimizations" that will magically cure all your problems. On any reasonably modern torrent client and OS this shouldn't be necessary.
  The torrent client will be capable of configuring its network
  settings properly and manual adjustments should not be necessary and will often do more harm than good.

You could try to switch to a different torrent application to see if that performs any better in your case.
Excluding the "incoming" folder from real-time scanning by your anti-virus can also make a big difference.

Comment: I suspect slow seeders or traffic shaping

Comment: Thanks for the info. I also tried qbittorrent but that showed the same thing. I don't have any antivirus and windows firewall is surely not getting in the way. I did reset TCP optimizations and turned to automatic configuration. Then I tried other torrents(more healthy ones) and speeds turn to expected as they should have. I am guessing slow seeders(as @Smock suggested) or TCP configuration to be a problem here. Anyways, everything is working fine now.